# org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, json

I'm trying to parse my json request to my model. I dunno what is wrong in this code. Syntax of json looks correct and annotations on Java model also. I don't know why I'm getting error like:

JSON IS :

```
[
{"Details":"Shows dsdsd details", "requestquery":"id=3915"},
{"Details":"chghar last 10 episodes","requestquery":"id=145434"},
{"Details":"last 10 episodes of reporters","requestquery":"id=1454391"}
]
```

My POJO CLASS ARE

```
public class ThirdPartyDetailsArray {

    @JsonProperty("")
    private List<ThirdPartyDetails> contentDetails;

    public List<ThirdPartyDetails> getContentDetails() {
        return contentDetails;
    }

    public void setContentDetails(List<ThirdPartyContentDetails> contentDetails)     
    {
        this.contentDetails = contentDetails;
    }

}

public class ThirdPartyDetails {

    private String Details;

    private String requestquery;

    public String getDetails ()
    {
        return Details;
    }

    public void setDetails (String Details)
    {
        this.Details = Details;
    }

    public String getRequestquery ()
    {
        return requestquery;
    }

    public void setRequestquery (String requestquery)
    {
        this.requestquery = requestquery;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [Details = "+Details+", requestquery = "+requestquery+"]";
    }

}
```

But I am getting Above error.
Anything wrong in my code.

Comment: Can you give the code use use for deserialization ? You shoudl pass straight ThirdPartyDetails[].class

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is correctly formatted.

Have you tried making the `Details` and `requestquery` properties public?